# Bash command substitution executing before earlier code

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal

```
ssh -i "path/to/my/key.key" ip.ip.ip.ip "mkdir a/a; sql 'query;' > a/a/file.txt; if [ -f a/a/file.txt ]; then if [ $(wc -l a/a/file.txt) -ge 2 ]; then echo 'done'; fi; fi; exit"
```

After connecting via ssh, I'm basically making a directory, writing a sql query to a file. If that file exists, then I check if its word count is greater than 1. If word count greater than 1, I echo done, then exit.

However, I get this error:

```
wc: a/a/file.txt open: No such file or directory
```

It seems as if the command substitution `$(wc -l a/a/file.txt)` is executing first (at least before the sql query), so the file hasn't been created yet. Is there some way to force this to execute in the order its written, or is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you have the string in double quotes so variables/command substitutions/etc. all happen on the calling side. You need single quotes or to escape the expansions to avoid that.

Comment: Also the output from `wc -l file` isn't directly usable in a `-gt` test it has the filename in it. Use `wc -l <file` to avoid that.

Comment: The `-f` test is not necessary; once `sql` returns, that file is guaranteed to exist because the shell creates it before it executes `sql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to protect the command substitution from being expanded before `ssh` is called; you can wrap the entire command in single quotes, or simply escape the `$` within the double quotes (shown here). (Newlines inserted for clarity; they aren't necessary, but can be used if you want.)

```
ssh -i "path/to/my/key.key" ip.ip.ip.ip "mkdir -p a/a
 sql 'query;' > a/a/file.txt
 [[ \$(wc -l < a/a/file.txt) -ge 2 ]] && echo 'done'"
```

The `-f` test is unnecessary; the shell creates the file before running `sql`, and the file will exist whether or not the command produces any output. The `exit` is unnecessary as well; the shell will exit as soon as the last command is executed anyway.

One (hacky?) way to avoid the command substitution altogether is to simply try to read 2 lines from the file with `read`:

```
ssh ... "mkdir -p a/a
 sql 'query;' > a/a/file.txt
 { read && read; } < a/a/file.txt && echo 'done'"
```

Comment: I'm dealing with a buggy version of sql which is why I have to do these checks in the first place. The query seems to have 3 types of errors. 2 types write a one line error message to the file, which is why I check if it's at least two lines. The third type exits without writing to file, which is why I check if the file exists.

Comment: If the file doesn't exist at all, that's not due to `sql`; the shell creates the target of a redirection before the associated command is ever run. The one-line error message does require the line count; I'll amend my answer.